# Way to async process all event handlers?

Tags: javascript, events, promise, async-await

I'm looking for a way to know when `event` that gets emitted and all of the handlers have finished firing.

The code below logs the following:

```
after do something
undefined
do something one
do something two
```

And what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
do something one
do something two
after do something
undefined
```

Here's the code:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

let event = new EventEmitter()

let doSomethingOne = Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('do something one'))
let doSomethingTwo = Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('do something two'))

event.on('myEvent', async function () {
  return await doSomethingOne()
})

event.on('myEvent', async function () {
  return await doSomethingTwo()
})

async function main() {
  event.emit('myEvent', {'name': 'tom'})
  // await event.finalized('myEvent')
  console.log('after do something')
}

main()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error.bind(console))
```

Is there an idea in events, promises, or javascript as a whole that would allow you to get a callback / promise / await all async event handlers?

Like this:

```
await event.finalized('myEvent')
```

> Note I'm aware that there's no real need to await one promise within an async function. It's just to show that these event handlers are async.

Comment: read http://bahmutov.calepin.co/promisify-event-emitter.html

Comment: If I understand correctly this could be what you're looking for? https://github.com/yortus/asyncawait however this seems to make the code act more sync (like generators) so may be insufficient if you really want your code to continue being async

Comment: look for gulp4's bach library in github gulpjs/bach repo. I believe is that what you want. It has .series and .parallel, you can customize and nest whatever you want.

Comment: rxjs to the rescue! https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

Answer (score 0):

I just created a node module [`event-as-promised`](https://github.com/reggi/event-as-promised) that allows you to `await` / `.then()` the `.emit()` handler.

```
let event = new EventAsPromised()

event.on('customerAdd', (data) => {
  let status = {'added': true}
  return Promise.resolve(status).delay(100)
})

event.emit('customerAdd', {'name': 'Thomas'})
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data) // => [{'added': true}]  
  })
```